# How to prevent exceeding matrix dimensions while dividing an image into blocks?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have an image which I want to divide into overlapping blocks.

I have set the box to be of size 8 rows and 8 columns, and the overlapping factor to be 4 rows/columns.

This is what I have written to solve this:

```
img = imread('a03-017-05.png');
overlap = 4
count = 1;
for i = 1:overlap:size(img,1)
    for j = 1:overlap:size(img,2)
        new{count} = img(i:i+8,j:j+8);
        count = count+1;
    end
end
```

This works right until it reaches the end of the image where `j+8` or `i+8` will go beyond the dimensions of the image. Is there any way to avoid this with minimal data loss?

Thanks

Comment: So if you have an image with 13 columns and you'll ignore the last column?

Comment: Have you tried `img(i:end,j:end)`?

Comment: Actually, your box size in the example is 9x9...

Comment: If available, use this function: http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html

Comment: @Daniel Does `blockproc` allow you to overlap the blocks?

Comment: @beaker: Yes, use the `'BorderSize'` parameter

Comment: @Daniel Thank you,I tried blockproc but was not too happy with the way the outputs are presented and the overlapping gives limited control. Thats why I wanted to do it manually

Comment: @Daniel Cool, I had completely missed that option. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to ignore the columns/rows that lie outside full sub-blocks, you just subtract the width/height of the sub-block from the corresponding loop ranges:

```
overlap = 4
blockWidth = 8;
blockHeight = 8;
count = 1;
for i = 1:overlap:size(img,1) - blockHeight + 1
    for j = 1:overlap:size(img,2) - blockWidth + 1
        ...
```

Let's say your image is 16x16. The block beginning at column `8` will account for the remainder of the columns, so having a starting index between 9 and 16 is pointless.

Also, I think your example miscalculates the block size... you're getting blocks that are 9x9. I think you want to do:

```
        new{count} = img(i:i+blockHeight-1,j:j+blockWidth-1);
```

As an example, in a 13x13 image with the code above, your row indices will be `[1, 5]` and the row ranges of the blocks will be `1:8` and `5:12`. Row/column 13 will be left out.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for. It was just a simple matter of subtracting the block size from the for loop, but it just wasn't clicking. Also you are right about the block size being bigger by 1, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you want them arranged but I did a checker board pattern, ie

```
x [] x [] ...
[] x [] x ...
```

So to do that

```
%The box size
k = 8;
%The overlap
overlap = 4;

%One layer of the checker board
new1 = mat2cell(img, [k*ones(1, floor(size(img,1)/k)), mod(size(img,1), k)], [k*ones(1, floor(size(img,2)/k)), mod(size(img,2), k)]);

%Get the overlap cells
img2 = img(overlap + 1:end - overlap, overlap + 1:end - overlap);

%Create the other part of the checker board
new2 = mat2cell(img2, [k*ones(1, floor(size(img2,1)/k)), mod(size(img2,1), k)], [k*ones(1, floor(size(img2,2)/k)), mod(size(img2,2), k)]);

%They will all end up in new
new = cell(size(new1) + size(new2));
new(1:2:end, 1:2:end) = new1;
new(2:2:end, 2:2:end) = new2;
```